# Нужна ли запятая между словами "и жаль и не жаль"

Tags: пунктуация

И больно сердцу, и легко, и жаль и не жаль, то куда-то манится, то, вдруг, сквозь смех заплакать хочется...

Answer (score 2):

**И больно сердцу и легко, и жаль и не жаль, то куда-то манится, то вдруг сквозь смех заплакать хочется...**

При повторении союза И запятая не ставится, если слова семантически связаны между собой, например имеют противоположное значение.

Одиночное наречие *вдруг* не стоит обособлять, даже в авторском варианте.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

2. При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом и, запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов): Кругом было и светло и зелено (Т.); Он носил и лето и зиму старую жокейскую кепку (Пауст.);

Comment: Расстановку запятых поддерживаю, но есть два вопроса. (1) Если это **сердце** манится, то не надо ли исправить согласование: "то ОНО куда-то манится"? (2) В современном языке можно сказать "сердце куда-то манится"?

Comment: Нашел у Даля: *Ему манится в Москву ехать*. Значит, это автору куда-то манится (хочется) ехать? А корректно ли без "ехать"?

Comment: Куда-то манится (куда-то тянет) - вроде бы безличное предложение. . ....А вообще  раньше глагол имел и другие значения: в низкие окна весело манится солнце  [И. А. Новиков. (1917-1919)] С нею жутко, от нее манится прочь, на воздух, на ветер, в толпу, меж людей [Н. С. Лесков. (1885)]

Answer (score 0):

Запятая - на усмотрение автора. Но тут я бы рекомендовал именно такое написание, без запятой.

Вообще обычно пара "и [что-то], и не [что-то]" при раздельном написании отрицательной  частицы не рассматривается как слова с противоположным значением, а лишь как однородные члены типа "объект-отрицание объекта" и написание с запятой вполне законно, особенно если это оправдано интонационно.

*И верю, и не верю счастью,

Гляжу с надеждою во тьму...*
(Бунин)
Источник: http://bunin-lit.ru/bunin/stihi/stih-712.htm

Исключение составляют "сросшиеся" сочетания, где запятая невозможна, правда в этих случаях обычно слитное написание частицы: "и быль и небыль".

Но в данном тексте, с учетом контекста лучше рассматривать именно как противопоставление. В ряду перечислений это оправдано, так как позволяет вычленять эту пару как единый член такого перечисления.

Так что авторское написание без запятой вполне понятно и оправдано. 
Как вариант можно рассматривать вариант с тире.

***И больно сердцу, и легко, и жаль - и не жаль, то куда-то манится, то вдруг сквозь смех заплакать хочется...***

PS Запятых вокруг "вдруг" я не понимаю совершенно.

PPS По поводу *"И больно сердцу, и легко"* - это отдельный разговор. Запятая тоже факультативна, но - в отличие от разбираемой - она не кажется мне лишней, тут нет прямого противопоставления противоположностей, да и интонационно она оправдана. Впрочем, все обсуждаемо.

Comment: "Авторское написание без запятой"(?) А у автора: "И больно сердцу, и легко" (с запятой) .

Comment: @М_Г  мы же про  другую запятую, между *"жаль"* и *"не жаль"*. По поводу "и больно(,) и легко" - да, это отдельная песня, тут запятая интонационная. Хотя можно обсуждать...

Comment: Несимметричный подход не радует глаз.

Comment: @М_Г ну это дело сугубо личного глаза. Впрочем, так я "симметрии" как таковой здесь не вижу. .